# xampp Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly, cause by forgot turn off before shutdown pc

Tags: xampp

I has been getting this error quite a lot of time recently. I realize that the errors are cause by I forgot turn of mysql when I shutdown my computer. I had try to remove ibdata1 in data folder, it not work for this situation. Following is my error log.

```
2016-08-15 12:11:33 1b48 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 8656625 and 8656625 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 8656635 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-08-15 12:11:33 6984 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-08-15 12:11:36 6984 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace drupaltest/variable uses space ID: 31 at filepath: .\drupaltest\variable.ibd. Cannot open tablespace livestream/tbl_user which uses space ID: 31 at filepath: .\livestream\tbl_user.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\livestream\tbl_user.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here
```

How to fix this by config or other method instead of reinstall xampp

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just did this and it worked:

1. exit Xampp server
2. go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
3. delete the ibdata1 file
4. restart xampp server

It should work

Comment: You try.
Add the following line below the [mysqld] section in the mysql config file (my.ini) and restart the apache web server and the mysql service afterwards.

[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 4

Comment: you change: [mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1

Comment: Get the same response

Comment: you deleted file .ibd??

Comment: No, I didn't remove any .ibd file

Comment: you remove .ibd file and test again.